# Rails "( LoadError ): run bundle install --local" when trying to create new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My system is Ubuntu 16.04.

I have ruby version 2.3.1.

I tried to install Rails.

So I ran the command:

```
sudo apt install ruby-railties
```

Then I tried to create a Project.

```
rails new FirstRailsProject
```

First try creating a new project I got an error along the lines `failled to require bundler`, so after a few searches on here I gave this command a try:

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Thought this command fixed it but I still get errors trying to create a new project.

So I gave up and figured I would ask for help, I copied in my output when I run the rails new command for more specific detail.

When I run `rails new FirstRailsProject` ( The error is at the very bottom )

```
  create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/mailers/.keep
  create  app/models/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/secrets.yml
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/assets.rb
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
    run  bundle install --local
  /usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
    run  bundle exec spring binstub --all 
 /usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
```

Comment: What is your rails version ?

Comment: Rails 4.2.6 @Hizqeel

Comment: Are you using RVM?  Have you run bundle `install --local` ? run this command `gem list` and check is there bundler gem installed locally

Comment: Can someone tell me if I took the correct steps on installing Rails? Should I have been able to create a new project after running $ sudo apt-get ruby-railties ? Did I skip any steps?

Comment: @Hizqeel I ran the `gem list` command and I did find `bundler (1.13.7)` listed.

Comment: what do you get if you type `which bundle`?

Comment: @EdmundLee I ran `which bundle` and got `/usr/local/bin/bundle
`

Comment: do this `rails new YourAppName --skip-bundle`, then `cd` into your project, then run `bundle`

Comment: @EdmundLee I was able to run the `rails new app --skip-bundle` than I `cd` into my directory and ran `bundle` and got a long output but recieved an error eventually  `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

Comment: do `sudo gem uninstall bundler` then do `gem install bundler`. What happened is your file system permission is set up incorrectly.

Comment: @EdmundLee I uninstalled successfully but running `gem install bundler` gives me this error `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.
` . Also how do I fix my file system permission?

Comment: do `which ruby` find out where your ruby is installed. I recommend using `rvm` or `rbenv` to manager your ruby and gemsets. You will have a much easier time moving forward

Comment: You need to export the path of ruby and bundle in your `.bashrc`  open `.bashrc` and add this line `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/"`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Hizqeel

Comment: Thanks for your help @EdmundLee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I highly recommend you not run sudo before you understand how permissions work.

In the long run, having a version management will save you time and headaches. You can either choose `RVM` or `Rbenv`.

Here's a link on how to install RVM onto your ubuntu.

https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm

After that, you can simple do `rvm install 2.3.3` or `rvm install any_version` to install a ruby version.

Then you do `gem install bundler`

`gem install rails`

This way, all your gems will be installed only under a certain version of ruby. You don't need to gain elevated permission and avoid using `sudo` command.

To clean up what you did.

Follow this

https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application

Comment: Do I need to uninstall anything before I follow these steps?

Comment: you can clean those up later. but leaving it is not going to affect these steps.

Comment: Would `gem install rails` overwrite the current rails I have? I'm afraid of installing  rails twice and getting more errors from them inflicting. Sorry if I'm asking too many questions, everything about rails is new to me.

Comment: It will not. This way, all the gems is going to be in `usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3`. And if you install a different version of ruby using RVM, you will have a complete different gemsets, meaning, you will need to do `gem install rails` for any new ruby version you install.